# Defining rectangle position relative to existing rectangle in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have created a rectangle in Paper.js and I would like to create a second rectangle. **More specifically, I want to position the second rectangle so that it is right beside the first rectangle.** However, I can't seem to do that. With my current code, I only get a single yellow rectangle:

```
var rect1 = new Path.Rectangle(view.center, new Size(50, 50));
rect1.fillColor = "yellow";


var rect2 = new Path.Rectangle(rect1.point + new Point(rect1.width, 0), new Size(50,50))
rect2.fillColor = "red";
```

The problem seems to be that defining rect2's position using rect1.point is not allowed. However, rect1.point is just the top left point of rect1, so rect1.point + new Point(rect1.width, 0) should give me another point.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way of doing this kind of things is using the information contained into [item.bounds](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#bounds).
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/bc/BDoIwDADQX1l6goQQJOGC8eTVA5Gj8zBGkYWxmVEhavx3B4aDxkPTrO360icY0SPkUHZIsoUIpK3n9ygccyhpw3bM4MQKQW189AVhLhqDUeEUSzSELlr6pXpgkCURy5Iw3HLHzfI7bpTWe6ut83s43FFrO3FYBtZYqfQ/9dlT2ZupB5+IbH/Ahr7ZWV3R9Ad1WHvRn1Y5FN3VKkMD5Kfz6w0=) demonstrating a possible solution to your case:

```
var rect1 = new Path.Rectangle(view.center, new Size(50, 50));
rect1.fillColor = "yellow";


var rect2 = new Path.Rectangle(rect1.bounds.bottomLeft, new Size(50,50))
rect2.fillColor = "red";
```

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to solve the problem. Do you know why my original approach wouldn't work though?

Comment: Yes, your approach doesn't work because `rect1.point` is undefined. `rect1` is a `Path` instance and a `Path` doesn't have any `point` property. What certainly mislead you is that the `Path.Rectangle` path constructor accepts a `point` but this is only a constructor argument.